# Passing ENV variables to database.yml in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, environment-variables

Here is my database.yml config:

```
development:
  adapter: ibm_db
  username: "username"
  password: "password"
  database: '*LOCAL'
  schema: <%= ENV['CA_SCHEMA'] %>
  ibm_i_isolation: 'none'
```

Here is my initializer:

```
module Ca2eModelExtractor
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.before_configuration do
      ENV['CA_SCHEMA']= 'XAMDL'
    end
  end
end
```

After running `rails c` I did `ENV['CA_SCHEMA']` and saw `XAMDL` as an output, so it works as expected. But when I run `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations`, I got a hash, where schema is nil. Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting `DATABASE_SCHEMA` in your environment, that may do what you want although what you tried should work.

Comment: Like `ENV['DATABASE_SCHEMA'] = 'XAMDL'`? Doesn't work

Comment: Did you restart spring? Just trying anything here.

Comment: And I guess I was also suggesting trying it with `export` from the shell or .env file just to try to isolate what isn't working here

Comment: I don't have a spring, and I need to change it in runtime.